# Proof of $\lim_{k\to \infty}{|x^k-x|\over { 1+|x^k-x|}}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, alternative-proof

Is there an easy way to prove that $$\lim_{k\to \infty}{|x^k-x|\over { 1+|x^k-x|}}=0$$ with $x\in \mathbb R$ without using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: If $|x|<1$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} |x^k-x|=|x|$. If $|x|=1$, $\lim_{k\to\infty}|x^k-x|=0$. If $|x|>1$, the $|x^k-x|$ becomes dominated by $x^k$ as $k$ becomes large enough.

Comment: Specify the range of $x$, for everybody's good.

Comment: Addendum (can't edit): if $x=-1$, this doesn't converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x|<1$, then $|x^k-x|=x-x^k$
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x-x^k}{1+x-x^k}=\frac{x}{1+x}.$$
If $|x|=1$, then
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|x^k-x|}{1+|x^k-x|}=0.$$
If $|x|>1$, then $|x^k-x|=x^k-x$
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^k-x}{1+x^k-x}=1-\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^k-x}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x>1$ or $0 > x >  -1$ and $k \to \infty$, $|x^k-x|=x^k-x$ since the thing inside the absolute value will be positive.

If $x<-1$ or $0 < x<1$ and $k \to \infty$, $|x^k-x|=x-x^k$ since the thing inside the absolute value will be negative.

If $x=0$ or $x=1$, $|x^k-x|=0$

Do two different limits, one for each case, and you will find your answer.

Thanks to Moya for pointing out the error.

Comment: Oops. Yes this too ^.

Answer (score 0):

If $x > 1$,
then this is *false*,
because
${|x^k-x|\over { 1+|x^k-x|}}
={-1+1+|x^k-x|\over { 1+|x^k-x|}}
={-1\over { 1+|x^k-x|}}+1
$
and
${-1\over { 1+|x^k-x|}}
\to 0
$
as $k \to \infty
$
since
$|x^k-x|
\to \infty
$.